# when button pressed trigger raised unhandled exception ora-01401

Tags: oracle, plsql, import, oracleforms

I am try to insert data from .CSV into `Oracle db`
Everything works fine, but after a couple of second I get error

```
when button pressed trigger raised unhandled exception ora-01401
```

I have around `1200 records` to insert, when I check in database I see that insert only around `630 record`.

```
declare 

   import_file text_io.file_type; 
   export_file text_io.file_type; 
   import_file_name varchar2(1000);
   export_file_name varchar2(1000);

   import_log_file text_io.file_type;
   import_log_file_name varchar2(1000);

   vec_importovano  number;
   brojac number;
   brojac_redova number;
   linebuf varchar2(5000);


   p_rbr     VARCHAR2(30);
   p_polica  VARCHAR2(30);
   p_banka   VARCHAR2(20);
   p_kontakt VARCHAR2(30);

  kraj_fajla number;

begin
    brojac_redova:=0;
    p_rbr:=100001;

    import_file_name := :Global.Lokacija_prenosa||:import.naziv_fajla||:Global.Ekstenzija_prenosa;
    import_file := text_io.fopen(import_file_name,'r');

    delete from zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude where banka is not null;
    commit;

    kraj_fajla := 0;  
    while kraj_fajla = 0 loop
  begin     
    brojac_redova:=brojac_redova+1;
    p_rbr:=p_rbr+1;
    text_io.get_line(import_file, linebuf);               

 if brojac_redova >= 2 then

   p_polica:=substr(linebuf, 1, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
  -- message(p_polica);
   p_kontakt:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,2) - instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
  -- message(p_kontakt);

   if instr(linebuf,';',1,3) > 0 then 
            p_banka := substr(linebuf, 
                            instr(linebuf,';',1, 2) + 1, 
                            instr(linebuf,';',1,3) - instr(linebuf,';',1,2)-1);

                 --message(p_banka);               
        else
          p_banka := substr(linebuf, 
                            instr(linebuf,';',1, 2) + 1);   
                --message(p_banka);                              
        end if; 

  -- IF p_rbr is not null then
         insert into ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE 
          (BROJ_POLICE,REDNI_BROJ,BROJ_PONUDE,BANKA)     
         values(
         p_polica,
         p_rbr,
         p_kontakt,
         p_banka);      
            commit;                   
   end if;
  -- end if;

     EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN kraj_fajla := 1;         
     end;

end loop;  
        if p_rbr is not null then
      update zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude set redni_broj=rownum;
        end if;
    text_io.fclose(import_file);
      message('Zavrseno prepisivanje fajla');
end;
```

What I  did so far, I increase the buffer size and increase data in database but again same problem.

Here is the data which cannot be inserted into database. So It stop over here and It display error.

```
4555219;773017/1;S-PREMIUM BA
4555220;1862014551963592;ZIR
4555223;1861814551965445;ZIR
4555224;1861634551963417;ZIR
4555226;234011;PBS
4555230;1862614551947169;ZIR
4555231;1862814551965880;ZIR
4555237;234002/1;PBS
4555238;233817/1;PBS
4555239;233982;PBS
4555240;233422;PBS
4555242;233820;PBS
4555243;1861614551961478;ZIR
4555244;1861824551967142;ZIR
4555246;1861644551966181;ZIR
4555247;1861214551966542;ZIR
4555248;1861814551967773;ZIR
4555249;1862224521502138;ZIR
4555250;1861224551967075;ZIR
4555251;1862214551967462;ZIR
4555252;1863214551968285;ZIR
4555253;1863414551943831;ZIR
4555254;1863414551966238;ZIR
4555254;1863414551966238;ZIR
4555255;1863414551962746;ZIR
4555256;107160825;NLB
4555257;107161767;NLB
4555258;107158740;NLB
4555259;107162747;NLB
4555260;107162658;NLB
4555261;107157891;NLB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to empty `linebuf` at the beginning of the loop

```
while kraj_fajla = 0 
loop
begin     
  linebuf := null;
```

before every repetition for populating the value of that variable.

By the way local variable(`p_banka`)'s length (`20`) might be not enough for the returning values. You may try to increase such as `150`.

Comment: No, the problem is in .CSV file
One column contain data like: S-PROMO BA in the agency column
After I change it it works perfect

Comment: It stopped here: 
4555219;773017/1;S-PREMIUM BA
This part makes problem: S-PREMIUM BA

Comment: @Robby perhaps, you may have carriage return(chr(13)) or line feed character(chr(10)). Against this, you can use `replace(linebuf,to_char(13),'')` and/or `replace(linebuf,to_char(10),'')`.

Comment: I try to add in third  column something like
p_banka := substr(linebuf,instr(linebuf,';',1, 2) + 1),
p_banka := substr(linebuf,instr(linebuf,'-',1, 2) + 1);  
But doesnt work

Comment: @Robby what's messaged when you add `message( length( substr(linebuf,instr(linebuf,'-',1, 2) + 1) ) );` just before those assignments.

Comment: I get in pop up message: 21,20,28,18

Comment: @Robby So, did you get the point :) ?. `p_banka   VARCHAR2(20);` ... 20 is less than 21 or 28 I mean.

Comment: Not sure :/ Help ?

Comment: I get point now. Since a couple of time I change this I couldnt notice where is problem
Thank you so much @Barbaros Özhan
Please update you answer that I can mark as correct one :)

Comment: Still have the same problem

   p_rbr     varchar2(20);
   p_polica  varchar2(10);
   p_banka   VARCHAR2(50);
   p_kontakt varchar2(30);

Comment: @Robby the length problem may exist for every local variables. You can try to message their iengths respectively as we did before.

Answer (score 0):

@
Check Length of all columns, this error is while inserting record length of string (from csv file)  is greater than table column width

Comment: You mean column in .CSV or column in database ?

Comment: Length of column in CSV is greater than same column in DB